# PyQt5 passing a string between two objects with custom signals and slots

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, signals-slots

Being far from an OO specialist, I was playing the last weeks with Qt5 in Python. The GUI I want to use is making use of QStackedWidget in which window designs are collected. I can switch from one window to the other by clicking a button. So far so good.

I want now to type a string in a LineEdit widget and when done, I would like to see this string showing up as label text in the second window. I understood from what I read that custom signals and slots can be used.

So I define a stringAdded signal as stringAdded = QtCore.pyqtSignal(['QString']) because I would like to send with the signal the string lineEdit.text().

In the class of the second window I specify the connection to the slot. The slot is a function that changes the lable text with the string received from the signal.

Now my questions:

1. Should I define the signal in all classes using it or only once?I understand the signal is a sort of a channel that must be created (see .pyqtSignal()) and to which a class should subscribe.
2. I consider that a string I typed in finished by clicking a "Load" button. In the slot connected to the btn_Load.clicked signal I emit the signal (see .emit()) and put the string from the lineEdit box in the emit function. Is this the way I send a string as a signal to whoever wants to receive the string?
3. In the class representing the second window with only a label and a button to return to the first window, I connect the signal with the slot self.signalPassed. How do I receive the string from the emitted signal in the slot for printing it out?
4. Can I avoid clicking a Load button in order to pass the string to the label in the second window? Would it be possible to trigger a signal just by typing enter after the input string?
5. What about QObject in the class definition? Why is this needed?

I try to obtain a working example on which I can further build, but the signal/slot mechanism is not at all clear to me after reading a lot on the internet.

The code added does not generate errors or warnings, the Load button works but the mechanism to receive the signal and the respective string does not work. The label text in the second window is not set.

A big thank you in advance for all hints!!!

Find below the code:

#!/usr/bin/env python3

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, Qt, pyqtSignal

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, QObject):
    stringAdded = QtCore.pyqtSignal(['QString'])        #Define a signal incl the string to be passed.
    def __init__(self, widget):
        self.widget = widget
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent= None)

        loadUi("lib/Main_Input.ui", self)
        self.btn_Exit.clicked.connect(self.clickedExit) # Just exit the app
        self.btn_Load.clicked.connect(self.clickedLoad) # emit the signal, print it and change window

    def clickedExit(self):
        sys.exit()

    def clickedLoad(self):
        
        if self.line_Input.text() != '':
            print(self.line_Input.text())
            self.stringAdded.emit(self.line_Input.text())
        self.widget.setCurrentIndex(1)
class MessageWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget, QObject):
    stringAdded = QtCore.pyqtSignal(['QString'])        #Define the same signal as the one in the previous class.
                                                        #Connect to the signal buss
    def __init__(self, widget):
        self.widget = widget
        super(MessageWindow, self).__init__(parent=None)
        loadUi("lib/Output.ui", self)
        self.btn_Back.clicked.connect(self.clickedBack)
        self.stringAdded.connect(self.signalPassed)     #Connect the signal to a slot.

    def clickedBack(self):
        self.widget.setCurrentIndex(0)

    def signalPassed(self):
        print('Signal passed')
        self.lbl_Main_Input.setText(self.stringAdded.signal)

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    widget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()

    firstPage = MainWindow(widget)
    widget.addWidget(firstPage)

    secondPage = MessageWindow(widget)
    widget.addWidget(secondPage)

    widget.setCurrentWidget(firstPage)
    widget.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The First window: Main_Input.ui converted into .py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'Main_Input.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.6
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(640, 201)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 40, 111, 17))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.line_Input = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.line_Input.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 90, 113, 29))
        self.line_Input.setObjectName("line_Input")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 90, 111, 17))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.btn_Load = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_Load.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 140, 97, 27))
        self.btn_Load.setObjectName("btn_Load")
        self.btn_Exit = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_Exit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(440, 140, 97, 27))
        self.btn_Exit.setObjectName("btn_Exit")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Home Window"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Type String"))
        self.btn_Load.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Load"))
        self.btn_Exit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exit"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The Second window: Output.ui converted into .py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'Output.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.6
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(640, 164)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 30, 241, 17))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.lbl_Main_Input = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.lbl_Main_Input.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 70, 181, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(22)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.lbl_Main_Input.setFont(font)
        self.lbl_Main_Input.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.lbl_Main_Input.setObjectName("lbl_Main_Input")
        self.btn_Back = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.btn_Back.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 120, 97, 27))
        self.btn_Back.setObjectName("btn_Back")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "String typed in from Main Window:"))
        self.lbl_Main_Input.setText(_translate("Form", "TextLabel"))
        self.btn_Back.setText(_translate("Form", "Back"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I saw his videos but apart from being difficult to understand it was, or C++ based or an application adding complexity I was not interested in, or it was about the built-in signals and slots. All this made it difficult for me to grasp the concepts. Therefore, I asked the question here.

Comment: I scanned everything I could find about custom signals and slots for the last two weeks. I  would be surprised not having found also the one you mentioned. Could you point me to the video you have in mind?

Comment: I found Hala back and indeed her videos are excellent but I did not found one about custom signals and slots.

Comment: To be honest, I suggest you to completely ignore those "tutorials" (quotes required), as they're made by somebody who clearly didn't know what they were doing and still get "views" (money) while providing a terrible amount of awful suggestions and bad practices, and completely ignoring their responsibilities. Seriously, please, just ignore them: at least 5-10 questions caused by such "Qt tutorials" are weekly deleted or closed as duplicates. In any case, keep in mind that you should only ask *one* question per post, so I suggest you to [edit] your post and focus on a *single, specific* aspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching on the internet did not bring me solutions, so I was obliged to try whatever I could, which took time. Finally, I concluded that I started from the wrong side, by combining widgets into a stacked widget and then using it. In QDesigner it is possible to design one stacked widget containing all screens one needs for an application. The stacked widget can then be loaded when a GUI class is instantiated. As a result, the stacked widget object contains all widgets as labels, buttons, combo-boxes, etc. for all screens. It is important to carefully choose object names or leave the default names generated by QDesigner what is slightly less convenient. The connections between signal and slots can then be simply added for all widgets, and all event handling functions are also added to the same class. In this way, the GUI block contains everything. Switching between screens is very simple making use of the self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex method and encoded or selected values are everywhere and all the time accessible.

About my 5 questions, because I was going in the wrong direction, it all complicated things. With the stackedWidget in QDesigner everything is packed and there is no need to pass information between object instantiations of different classes. The solution found contains now the complete running of my application, counting for the time being 4 screens and this is only the beginning, and the GUI is just one class with a lot of event handling functions.